# Connection Refused Error Testing Golang API in Local Docker Environment

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to deploy a Go REST API to a local Docker container for testing. Deployment succeeds, but when I try to POST to the API, I receive the following error:

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081`

Here is my Dockerfile. I've already built the application locally and the binary is located at */web-admin-api*:

```
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /web-admin-api

COPY . /web-admin-api

CMD ["/web-admin-api/application"]

EXPOSE 8081
```

And here's the Docker compose file:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  app:
    container_name: web-admin-api
    hostname: web-admin-api
    restart: on-failure:3
    environment:
      GET_HOSTS_FROM: dns
        ports:
          - 8081:8081
        networks:
          - local

networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

How can I get this set-up so that I can POST requests locally?

Comment: When you set up the listener in your application, what do you set the bind address to?  (If it's `127.0.0.1:8081` it won't be accessible from outside its own container; use `:8081` instead.)  (Also `FROM scratch` images can be tricky, so confirm the container is actually starting up.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to post with `host.docker.internal` as the address instead of `127.0.0.1`

You can read more about it at the documentation link  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds